# No puedo consumir una REST API en Ionic 4 con un servidor creado en NodeJS

Tags: mysql, nodejs, typescript, rest, ionic4

Intento consumir la REST API en Ionic 4, cree todos los recursos en un servicio desde mi frontend, en mi backend cree un servidor nodejs, al probar mi servicio de nodejs algún programa de consultas funciona perfecto, por ejemplo Insomnia, pero en Ionic no me los carga, entonces cree una API temporal en Json para probar y sí me deja consumir los datos, incluso los datos son iguales.

https://github.com/JMSOFTCR/Ionic4-crud-market.git

https://github.com/JMSOFTCR/API-REST-NODEJS-MYSQL.git

Se me complica un poco copiar ciertas partes del código porque funcionan anidadas a otras partes, entonces voy a dejar los repositorios, son muy pequeños en realidad, no espero que se pierdan entre los archivos ya que sólo cuenta con un módulo de productos en ambos repositorios.

NOTA: No sé si esto es permitido, de no ser así me disculpo e intento adjuntar el código de alguna manera.

Edit: 
NodeJS

```
import { Request, Response } from "express";

import { connect } from "../database";

import { Products } from "../interfaces/Products";

export async function getProducts(req: Request, res: Response): Promise<Response | void>{
    const conn = await connect();
    const products = await conn.query('SELECT * FROM products');
    res.json(products[0]);
}

export async function createProducts(req: Request, res: Response): Promise<Response | void>{
    const newProducts: Products = req.body;
    const conn = await connect();
    await conn.query('INSERT INTO products set ?', [newProducts])
    return res.json({
        message: 'Product created'
    });
}

export async function getProduct(req: Request, res: Response): Promise<Response | void>{
    const id = req.params.productId;
    const conn = await connect();
    const products = await conn.query('SELECT * FROM products where id = ?', [id]);
    return res.json(products[0]);
}

export async function deleteProduct(req: Request, res: Response): Promise <Response | void>{
    const id = req.params.productId;
    const conn = await connect();
    await conn.query('DELETE FROM products WHERE id = ?', [id]);
    return res.json({
        message: 'Product deleted'
    });
}

export async function updateProduct(req: Request, res: Response): Promise<Response | void>{
    const id = req.params.productId;
    const updateProduct: Products = req.body;
    const conn = await connect();
    await conn.query('UPDATE products SET ? WHERE id = ?', [updateProduct, id]);
    return res.json({
        message: 'Product updated'
    });
}



export interface Products {
    id?: string;
    category_id: number;
    name: string;
    stock: number;
    description: string; 
    image_url: string;
    created_at: Date;
}
```

Mi interfaces en el NodeJS

ahora voy con la parte de Ionic 4

```
  import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders, HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Products } from '../models/products';
import { Observable, throwError } from 'rxjs';
import { retry, catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ApiService {

  base_path = 'http://localhost:3000/products'

  constructor(private http: HttpClient ) { }

  // Http Options
  httpOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({
      'Content-type': 'application/json'
    })
  }

  //Handle API Error 
  handleError(error: HttpErrorResponse){
    if (error.error instanceof ErrorEvent) {
      //A client-side or network error ocurred
      console.error('An error occurred:', error.error.message);
    }else {
      //The backend returned an unsuccessful response code
      //The response body may contain clues as to what went wrong
      console.error(
        `Backend returned code ${error.status}` +
        `Body was: ${error.error}`);
    }
    // Return an observable with user-facing error message
    return throwError(
      'Something bad happened; please try again later');
  };

  // Create a new item
  createItem(item): Observable<Products> {
    return this.http
      .post<Products>(this.base_path, JSON.stringify(item), this.httpOptions)
      .pipe(
        retry(2),
        catchError(this.handleError)
      )
  }

  //get single products data by ID
  getItem(id): Observable<Products> {
    return this.http
    .get<Products>(this.base_path + '/' + id)
    .pipe(
      retry(2),
      catchError(this.handleError)
    )
  }

  //get products data
  getList(): Observable<Products> {
    return this.http
    .get<Products>(this.base_path)
    .pipe(
      retry(2),
      catchError(this.handleError)
    )
  } 

  //update Item by id
  updateItem(id, item): Observable<Products> {
    return this.http 
    .put<Products>(this.base_path + '/' + id, JSON.stringify(item), this.httpOptions)
    .pipe(
      retry(2),
      catchError(this.handleError)
    )
  }

  //Delete item by id
  deleteItem(id) {
    return this.http
    .delete<Products>(this.base_path + '/' + id, this.httpOptions)
    .pipe(
      retry(2),
      catchError(this.handleError)
    )
  }

}
```

el listar

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ApiService } from '../services/api.service'

@Component({
  selector: 'app-list',
  templateUrl: 'list.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['list.page.scss']
})
export class ListPage implements OnInit {
productsData: any;

   constructor(
     public apiService : ApiService 
   ) {
    this.productsData = [];
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getAllProducts();
  }

  getAllProducts(){
    //get saved list of products
    this.apiService.getList().subscribe(response => {
      console.log(response);
      this.productsData = response;
    });  
  }

  delete(item) {
    //Delete item in Products data
    this.apiService.deleteItem(item.id).subscribe(Response => {
      //update list after delete id successfull
      this.getAllProducts();
    });
  }

}
```

la vista de listar

```
<ion-header>
    <ion-toolbar>
      <ion-buttons slot="start">
        <ion-menu-button></ion-menu-button>
      </ion-buttons>
      <ion-title>
        Products
      </ion-title>
    </ion-toolbar>
  </ion-header>

<ion-content padding>
  <table class="table">
    <tbody>
      <ion-list>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th scope="col">ID</th>
            <th scope="col">Name</th>
            <th scope="col">Category ID</th>
            <th scope="col">Stock</th>
            <th scope="col">Actions</th>   
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tr *ngFor="let item of productsData">
         <td>{{item.id}}</td>
          <td>{{item.name}}</td>
          <td>{{item.category_id}}</td>
          <td>{{item.stock}}</td>
          <td style="display: flex">
              <ion-button color="warning" size="small" routerLink='/update/{{item.id}}'>
                <ion-icon name="create"></ion-icon>
              </ion-button>
              <ion-button color="danger" size="small" (click)="delete(item)">
                <ion-icon name="trash"></ion-icon>
              </ion-button>
            </td>
      </tr>
      </ion-list>
    </tbody>
  </table>
<ion-button [routerLink]="['/create']">
      Add Products
    </ion-button>
</ion-content>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mi problema era que no había concedido permiso con cors, por esa razón al intentar accesar a la información el sistema negaba todo acceso, tuve que crear un middleware para poder accesar a la información.

```
this.app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Authorization, X-API-KEY, Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Access-Control-Allow-Request-Method');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE');
    res.header('Allow', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE');
    next();
});
```

esto va dentro de mi archivo app.ts